# Titanium scrollableView

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

I developing an application in Titanium. A hava a code with scrollableview.
It is working in Android but doesn't work in IOS, and not show error messages.
The code:

```
exports.imagescroller = function(images, imgWidth, imgHeight){

var imageCollection = images;
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'transparent',

});
if(imgWidth == null) {
    imgWidth = "100%";  
}

if(imgHeight == null) {
    imgHeight = "100%";
}

var scrollGallery = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    layout:'horizontal',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true,
});
var viewCollection = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imageCollection.length; i++) {
  var innerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout:'horizontal',
  });
  var item = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        width : imgWidth,
        height: imgHeight,
        imageID:i,
        defaultImage: imageCollection[0]
  });
  if (i < 3) {
    item.image = imageCollection[i];
  }

  innerView.add(item);
  viewCollection.push(innerView);
}

scrollGallery.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    if (scrollGallery.currentPage < (imageCollection.length-1)) {
        var nxt = scrollGallery.currentPage+1;
        scrollGallery.views[nxt].children[0].image = imageCollection[nxt];
    }
});
scrollGallery.views = viewCollection;

window.add(scrollGallery);
return window;
```

};

I use this in the window:

```
var Scroller = require("imagescroller");

window = Scroller.imagescroller(allData['images']);
```

Please help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the more cross platform `scrollend` event:

```
scrollGallery.addEventListener('scrollend', function(e){
    .......
});
```

Also try giving your ScrollableView an explicit width and height, just to rule that out:

```
var scrollGallery = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    layout:'horizontal',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true,
    width : "100%"
    height : "100%"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and its working , before post i tried it.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#123'
});
var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#246'
});
var view3 = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#48b'
});

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    views : [view1, view2, view3],
    showPagingControl : true,
    layout : 'horizontal',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : true,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : true,
});

win.add(scrollableView);
win.open();
```

Answer (score -1):

its works in android when you set the height of view more then the screen, or set the height of view , Ti.UI.SIZE
it works

Comment: The author stated that it already works in Android. The author is looking for a way to get this to work in iOS.